# Is it possible to use py.test fixtures in doctest files?

Tags: python, pytest

We use py.test in a project and use fixtures for most test cases. But I see no possibility to use fixtures in doctest files.

To give an example with some code snippets: I have a browser fixture in conftest.py like:

```
@fixture
def browser(request):
    from wsgi_intercept import zope_testbrowser
    browser = zope_testbrowser.WSGI_Browser()
    [...]
    return browser
```

and use it in the file test_browser.txt like:

```
>>> browser.open('some_url')
>>> browser.url == 'some_url'
True
```

But I can't see a way to get the fixture into a doctest file. Is this possible at all with py.test?

Comment: I believe doctests should show working examples, so it does not make any sense to use fixtures. If you are using them with testing purposes instead of documenting the behaviour then you should probably translate them into unittests.

Comment: I can't really understand your point here why this is not making sense. Yes, doctests show working examples, in this case as functional tests. I just want to hold the same configuration in one central place, in a fixture I already use for functional testing in unittest like tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't supported at the moment.  pytest would need to know at collection time which fixtures are going to be used in a doctest.  If we can come up with a way to declare which fixtures are going to be used, it shouldn't be hard to add support to `_pytest/doctest.py`  Maybe it's also possible to automatically find out which fixtures a doctest needs, not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Meanwhile I saw the doctest-fixture option in nose(https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=fixtures#cmdoption--doctest-fixtures) and thought it should be possible. But now I know that it is just not implemented yet.

Comment: Have you tried the nose-doctest-fixture support and are happy with it?  I think it would be nice to have a special syntax within the doctest text itself to specify fixtures.  I am not using doctest currently myself so i'd be happy about suggestions. Something like a line with ".. pytest-fixtures: name1, name2, name3" could be pre-scanned at collection time, and then be setup at execution time to become part of the "globs" the doctest executes with.

Comment: No, I don't tried it, only read the documentation(https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html). The doctest setup and teardown methods described there seems to be doctest specific. If I understand your suggestion right the same fixtures I already have can also be used for the doctests. As this is what I looked for, I favourite the latter if there. Do you think it is worth an issue?

Comment: Yes it is worth an issue.  Note that as i am not using doctest much myself, i'd really appreciate if you write down as exactly as possible what you would like to see.  And keeping it minimal of course makes it more likely me or someone gets to implement it. Note that _pytest/doctest.py is not a very big plugin so you might even try something yourself - i am going to try to support it of course.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/pull-request/25) attempting to implement this over at the [pytest repository](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest).  It provides two globals to doctest files, i.e. `fixture_request` and `get_fixture` (which is a convenience shortcut for `fixture_request.getfuncargvalue`).  The intended use is:

```
>>> browser = get_fixture('browser')
>>> browser.open('some_url')
```

This is different from the `.. pytest-fixtures: ...` line as suggested by Holger above, but was easier to implement... :)  Needless to say, it's up for discussion, of course!